# Display HTML <title></title> content c#

Tags: c#, html

Can anyone tell me how to display the title of a HTML webpage in a c# application using a webpage document that a user has wrote

Comment: There are tons of html parsers for C#. You can even do this with regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this. First you need to get the whole html response and traverse through it to scrap the text between the title element.

```js
public class TitleScraper {

private string url;

public TitleScraper(string url) { 
this.url = url; 
} 

public string Title { get; set; } 

public void Scrape() { 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.url); 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream(); 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data); 
string html = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
string regex = @"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)"; 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
Title = ex.Match(html).Value.Trim(); 
}

} 

//Note: If you have you are trying to read from a document file instead of the URL, You can use the following instead

public void Scrape() { 

string filePath = @"c:\user\filename.doc"; //location to your file
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
string regex = @"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)"; 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
Title = ex.Match(text).Value.Trim();

}
```

Comment: I have the HTML code as a document, will that make it easier?

Comment: I have edited the code and added what you can do when you are reading the HTML from the document instead of from a web URL.